# How to change the way eclipse showing suggestion?

Tags: eclipse

[image]

As you can see in the picture, I don't want the blue color suggestions. How do I change that?

Also I don't want that black color background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ach. Unfortunately that's pretty difficult. The background color of that pop-up is set by the operating system. It looks like you're running on Ubuntu with a darker theme. You have two choices:

1. Choose a different theme.
2. Live with the semi-illegible colors. If you click on the error marker on the left, it'll show up with a more tollerable black-on-white window.

Comment: Thanks JOhn for the quick reply..yes i am using ubuntu

Comment: It wasn't difficult to fix at all. Check out Rafee's answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [this guide](http://weblog.avp-ptr.de/20120728/how-to-fix-eclipse-colors-for-autocompletion-and-tooltips/) to change the tooltip colours just for Eclipse, rather than changing them for the whole desktop environment.

Comment: This is a much better answer than the accepted one. Ubuntu 12.04 lost the custom theme option and GNOME Color Chooser was also useless.

Answer (score 1):

- Select "Change Desktop Background"
- Select "Theme" from the tabs.
- Click 
  "Customize"
- Select "Colors" from the
  tabs.
- Change the "Background" of the
  "Tooltips" as you like .
- The change
  will be visible at eclipse. 
  (On basis
  of Ubuntu 10.10)

Comment: In Ubuntu 11.10 and 12.04 the customize button is missing.  Instead, install gnome-color-chooser and go to `Specific->Tooltips` and check the override boxes to use a black foreground over pale yellow background.

Answer (score 1):

**eclipse Preferences** 

    **->** **General** 

     **->** **Appereance** 

       **->** **"Colors and Fonts"** 

          **->** **Java** 

          **->** **"Javadoc background"**

Answer (score -1):

go to sourcehover foreground and change the color

1. to windows
2. Click on Editor tab
3. you will see source hover  background, parameter hint foreground change the color